# Windows 7 login without credential prompt using powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, automation

I'm trying to automate a task using powershell and I need the computer to restart multiple times. I'm doing this by scheduling a job that runs at startup that executes different scripts, and after that I use `Restart-Computer` to reboot the pc.

My problem is that I want it to be completely autonomous, but right now I need to input username and password at startup to access my profile. I know that if there is a single user on the machine and if it doesn't have a password it gets logged in automatically, but there are two users on the machine. Is there a way to automatically login after a reboot to a pre-selected windows account with powershell? Thanks

EDIT: I also have to execute programs that have a GUI, so I need authentication anyways.

Comment: If you're using a scheduled task why do you need to login? Have it run as System, and run at computer startup, and have it run whether the user is logged in or not.

Comment: There is more then one scheduled task, every one of them is created by a different powershell script. 

`$nextstep = New-JobTrigger -Once -AtStartup`
`Register-ScheduledJob -Name PartX -Trigger $nextstep -ScriptBlock {powershell -file 'C:\Part X.ps1'}`

Every script creates a task that calls the next script before rebooting the system. Is it going to work even without authentication?

Comment: if you set your tasks to run as the system account and run on startup it should work fine.

Comment: As I wrote on the edit part of the post, the powershell script runs some GUI executables, so I need to login

Comment: Why does having a GUI matter?

Comment: In the powershell script I need to excute some executables that have GUIs and require user interaction (wich I've already simulated by making powershell send characters). Aldo I need to run everything as administrator and a part of the code ad an unprivileged user (thing that I did by popping an unprivileged powershell session)